# how to get characters with accent from NSEvent

Tags: cocoa, keyboard-events

When I press `^` or `` ` `` and then `a` or `e` I get only `a` or `e` instead of `â` or `é`.

This is my code:

```
- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent*)event
{
  NSString* str = [event characters];
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

keyDown: only gives the characters for the key you currently are pressing down.  Characters that take more than one keystroke show up as a separate keyDown: call for each keystroke.  If you want to see typed characters instead of individual keypresses, override -insertText: instead.

Comment: do I have to call [self interpretKeyEvents:[NSArray arrayWithObject:event]]; inside keyDown?

Comment: Yes.  But once your needs become more complicated than -keyDown:, you should take a good hard look at NSTextField/NSTextView.  There are a couple dozen text methods that can fall out of -interpretKeyEvents: besides -insertText:, and the text class handles all of them for 'free'.