# Cocoa/Objective-C on macOS - handle accented characters via keyDown:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard

I have an application that processes keystrokes via keyDown:.  This works well so far, with the exception of two problems (the other one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088407/objective-c-on-macos-get-keydown-for-shifttab-in-view)).

The problem in this question is about accented characters, i.e. letters that are combined with a dead char, e.g. *á*

I'm handling keyDown: fine so far (accessing the characters through [nsevent characters]). It's just that I never get accented characters.

I get a keyDown: event for the accent ´ where [nsevent characters] is zero length, but essentially I guess I don't know what to do with it.

The next characters in keyDown: is the unaccented version, e.g. an /a/.

I also know about *selectNextKeyView:* but ideally I am looking for a way to get the system to pass the combination to keyDown: for normal handling (incidentally keyUp: is called correctly for it).

So essentially my question is: Why does my handleKeyEvent: never get an *á* through [nsevent characters], only an /a/?

Or how should I access the characters otherwise?

```
        -(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)nsevent
        {
            BOOL didit= [self handleKeyEvent:nsevent isRaw:FALSE isUp:FALSE];
            if (!didit)
                [super keyDown:nsevent];
        }


        -(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)nsevent
        {
            BOOL didit= [self handleKeyEvent:nsevent isRaw:FALSE isUp:TRUE];
            if (!didit)
                [super keyUp:nsevent];
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100131/how-to-get-characters-with-accent-from-nsevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Courtesy of questions already answered (see the two links near the top of the code), I was aböle to solve this via unicode routines UCKeyTranslate().

The function below requires a persistent UInt32 to store the deadKeyState across calls, but that's all it took.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  translate keyDown to true unichar via inputlayout
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
NSString *
translateInputForKeyDown(NSEvent *event, UInt32 *deadKeyState) const
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547007/convert-key-code-into-key-equivalent-string
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263618/convert-virtual-key-code-to-unicode-string

    const size_t unicodeStringLength = 4;
    UniChar unicodeString[unicodeStringLength]= { 0, };
    UniCharCount reallength= 0;
    NSString *nsstring= nil;

    TISInputSourceRef fkis= TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
    if (fkis) {
        CFDataRef cflayoutdata= (CFDataRef)TISGetInputSourceProperty(fkis, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData);
        const UCKeyboardLayout *keyboardlayout= (const UCKeyboardLayout *)CFDataGetBytePtr(cflayoutdata);
        CGEventFlags flags = [event modifierFlags];
        UInt32 keymodifiers = (flags >> 16) & 0xFF;

        UCKeyTranslate(keyboardlayout,
                            [event keyCode], kUCKeyActionDown, keymodifiers,
                            LMGetKbdType(), 0,
                            deadKeyState,
                            unicodeStringLength, &reallength, unicodeString);
        ::CFRelease(fkis);
    }


    if (reallength>0) {
        nsstring= (NSString *)CFStringCreateWithCharacters(kCFAllocatorDefault, unicodeString, reallength);
    }

    return nsstring;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D This was a huge help. Let me just add that you need to include "Carbon/Carbon.h" and "CoreServices/CoreServices.h" and link to Carbon.framework to make this work.

Comment: Hi, any suggestion on how to get accented character in keyDown function, given a user presses a key and holds for the accented characters overlay to appear and then selects one of the accented character.